# SVG's SMIL animations are deprecated - Animate SVG circle's cy- and cx-property with CSS only?

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG in my html:

```
<img class="svg-loader" width="60" height="60" src="preloader.svg">
```

This SVG contains 3 circles which are animated inline to rotate and change their cy- and cx-position:

```
<svg width="57" height="57" viewBox="0 0 57 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="preloader-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(244,117,51);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(245,0,87);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2">
            <circle cx="5" cy="50" r="5" fill="url(#preloader-gradient)">
                <animate attributeName="cy"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     values="50;5;50;50"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="cx"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     values="5;27;49;5"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </circle>
            <circle cx="27" cy="5" r="5" fill="url(#preloader-gradient)">
                <animate attributeName="cy"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     from="5" to="5"
                     values="5;50;50;5"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="cx"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     from="27" to="27"
                     values="27;49;5;27"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </circle>
            <circle cx="49" cy="50" r="5" fill="url(#preloader-gradient)">
                <animate attributeName="cy"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     values="50;50;5;50"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="cx"
                     from="49" to="49"
                     begin="0s" dur="2.2s"
                     values="49;5;27;49"
                     calcMode="linear"
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The Chrome console throws a warning that *"SVG's SMIL animations (, , etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead".* So the question is if it is possible to replace the inline animation completely with CSS animations.

Now, it is trivial to rotate the complete SVG infinitely in CSS for 360 degrees:

```
.svg-loader {
  -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

However, I am stuck with the CSS animation of the cy-positions for each circle and not sure if this possible.

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Not in svg1.1, maybe in svg2 but it's still in draft. Note that SMIL isn't really deprecated: only chrome stopped its support for it, and IE never started it. However you can find js polyfills that will make it work in both chrome and IE e.g, search for fakeSmile , developped for IE, but I guess it works for chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kaiido before:

> SMIL isn't really deprecated: only chrome stopped its support for it, and IE never started it

But you can use css animations to achieve the same result.

You have to put the css inside the svg file or put the svg inline, using a img tag with external markup has limitations.

For example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 57 57" width=57 height=57>
 <style>
  @keyframes path{
   25%{ transform: translate(0,0); }
   50%{ transform: translate(0,-44px); }
   75%{ transform: translate(-45px,-22px); }
   100%{ transform: translate(0,0); }
  }
  .circle{
   animation: path 2.2s linear infinite;
   fill: red;
  }
 </style>
 <circle cx="49" cy="50" r=5 class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

But still above example will not work inside IE and Edge, you could resolve it with:

- code it interally with HTML and CSS
- split the svg in multiple svgs and animate the svg tags
- use JS (inside the svg file or inline)

Small example with the second solution:

```css
@keyframes path{
 25%{ transform: translate(0,0); }
 50%{ transform: translate(0,-44px); }
 75%{ transform: translate(-45px,-22px); }
 100%{ transform: translate(0,0); }
}
svg{
 animation: path 2.2s linear infinite;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
.circle{
 fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
 <circle cx=5 cy=5 r=5 class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: At least in Firefox v48.0 your first code snippet does not animate, while your second code snippet does animate.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately firefox doesn't support cx and cy as css properties. I fixed the example with a transform instead. It will make a bit harder, but still doable. JS will be the easiest solution.